# web api 2 404 (not found) GET Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

Hello I have this function of a simple validation to two inputs
Im using this function in the "IF" Of my Ajax Function and i get an 404 error

but when i remove this simple "IF" my AJAX Function is working perfect i would like for some help

```
    function signInValidation(userNameLogin, passwordLogin) {
    if (userNameLogin == "" || passwordLogin == "") {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#effect").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#effect").fadeOut(2000);
        })
    }
}
```

And i Have this Function with AJAX GET

```
    function GetUserLoginDetails() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#logInBtn').click(function (e) {

            var UserName = $('#_logInUserName').val();
            var Password = $('#_logInPassword').val();

            if (signInValidation(UserName, Password)){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost:56267/api/Users/GetUser' + '/' + UserName + '/' + Password,
                    type: 'Get',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        console.log(data);
                        window.location.replace("http://localhost:59472/Views/UserPage.html");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        console.log('Error in Operation');
                    }
                })
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Your `signInValidation` method doesn't seem to return anything?

Comment: and also, why are you using so many times `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your ajax not being run is due to your `signInValidation` isn't returning anything, the following is probably what you should modify your `signInValidation` method to:

```
function signInValidation(userNameLogin, passwordLogin) {
    if (userNameLogin == "" || passwordLogin == "") {
        $("#effect").fadeIn(1000);
        $("#effect").fadeOut(2000);
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your `signInValidation` method will now return `true` if a both a username and password are set, otherwise, it will return `false`, this will get checked in your if statement.

Also, `$(document).ready()` should not be used in the manner you're using it. `$(document).ready()` get called when the document gets loaded, there should be no need to use within your `signInValidation` method. You can read up more about it [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Thank you very much 
I have fixed it

Comment: @AdiOz No problem! Please mark the answer as correct, if it helped